# Is there a way to make a link look like a referral from any of the social media platform though the link is clicked directly?

Tags: bots, social-media, referrals, traffic-simulation

I kindly need a guide on how to make a website link appear to be a referral link from either Facebook, WhatsApp, Twitter, telegram etc so that even when clicked directly, it will appear as if the traffic is coming from the social media platform.

I tried using the utm parameters but it didn't take effect as expected. utm_source=facebeook.com&utm_medium=social

Comment: "it will appear as if the traffic is coming from the social media platform" - how do you check that?

Comment: @NicoHaase for instance for a website, google analytics and let's say YouTube video, from the analytics of YouTube studio

Comment: And what's the problem with that? Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. "It didn't take effect" is a pretty vague description